# MVC5 Application - AspNetUserRoles empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an **Asp.Net MVC 5.0 Application** that use **Identity 2.0** provider.

The application has two role **ADMINISTRATOR** and **ASPNET_IDENTITYMANAGER** and
it properly tests the roles even in the Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ASPNET_IDENTITYMANAGER")]
public ActionResult Idm()
{
     return Redirect("/Idm");
}
```

Even if I check it by code:

```
<b>Administrator</b>: @User.IsInRole("ADMINISTRATOR")<br />

<b>IDM Admin</b>: @User.IsInRole("ADMINISTRATOR")<br />
```

Now, I can't understand why the **AspNetUserRoles** is empty...

The **AspNetUserClaims** table is filled properly...

I don't know if act if its all ok or not...

Some one can give me an explaination ?

This image shows how the tables are filled: [AspNet Tables (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYYyN.png)

Thanks!
Dario